# Ran auto-updates on Ubuntu 12.04 and grub2 lost Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, bootloader

I have a dual boot system with two hard drives -- one for Windows 7 and the other for Ubuntu (now 3.5.0-43). I ran the most recent Ubuntu updates and lost my Windows 7 entry in grub. I've attempted running `sudo update-grub2`, os-prober, manually adding the "40_custom" entry in /etc/grub.d/, and surfing around for a solution. So far, it seems that nobody else has solved this problem.

I ran boot-repair and created the paste link -- http://paste.ubuntu.com/6466121/. Another oddity is that I am not able to do anything other than generate the "BootInfo" using boot-repair. I only get the "About", "Quit", and "Create a BootInfo summary (to get help by email or forum)" when I run the application.

I appreciate any information for how I might be able to re-add this entry... and how I can prevent future updates/upgrades from breaking this configuration again.

Answer (score 0):

Line 795 of your Boot-Repair log, we can see the `blkid` command returns nothing. You can mark yourself "Affected" by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/1216688

Running Boot-Repair from a `live-disk` (eg from Boot-Repair-Disk) may solve the issue. If not, indicate the new URL that will appear.